# Push down bottom divs when slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I hope this is a simple question im trying to push down the divs on my bottom row when my new element slides down on click

heres a link to my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/

heres my jquery

```
  $('li').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
  });
```

heres my html

```
 <ul style="list-style: none;">
  <li>
   <div style="width: 156px; height: 156px; border: solid #cfcfcf 1px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; color: #cfcfcf;"> 156px X 156px</div>

   <div class="outer">
     <div class="inner">
    </div>   
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You should `slideDown` the entire elment you want to move because when you slide things, they become absolutely positioned and don't affect the flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added jQuery UI for the duration on toggleClass.

http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/3/

**JS**

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.outer{position: absolute; width: 100%; background: black; top: auto; display: none; text-align: left;}
li.active {margin-bottom:100px;}
```

Comment: this works pretty good but on my site theres going to be more then four rows of boxes..its going to be responsive so the boxes are going to fill up the screens width......right now when theres more than four boxes the outer div that is sliding down is pushing the other four boxes down with it

Comment: Ahh well that's a bit trickier as the # of boxs in a row is unknown. But you won't be able to push down the next row using absolute positioning regardless. I'll try to think of an alternative.

Comment: Do you want the black bar to fill up the bottom of the row?

Comment: yeah the black bar should be the width of the brower window

Comment: Updated answer, I added jQuery UI to use the duration on toggleClass, but I suppose if you're not using it already, .animate() would work as well.